# How can I fire an event that depends on 2 form inputs meeting a certain criteria?

Tags: javascript, onclick, logical-operators, onkeyup

I want to show/hide elements on the page depending on whether 2 form inputs match. So in this example, if a text field is greater than 100000 and a radio button has a certain value, said elements will show. If correct radio is still selected, but the numerical value drops below 100000, then elements hide. (This code is part of a much larger script, in case it doesn't make sense).

It works for the most part, but the text field's `onchange`/`onkeyup` event doesn't fire on its own when used with a radio value `onclick` event. I have to reclick the radio button for a changed text field value to fire the event. (And it is not an `onblur` issue. `onchange` works fine on its own, but not with a logical `&&` operator.)

```
    <li id="f-container-applicant-bondamount">
        <label for="f-applicant-bondamount">Amount of Bond</label>
        <input type="text" name="ApplicantBondAmount" id="f-applicant-bondamount" onkeypress="showMoreInfo(this);" />
    </li>

    <li id="f-container-applicant-is"> 
        <label for="f-applicant-is">Applicant is...</label> 
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="f-applicant-is_0">
                    <input type="radio" name="ApplicantIs" id="f-applicant-is_0" value="Administrator" onclick="showMoreInfo(this);" />
                    Administrator
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="f-applicant-is_1">
                    <input type="radio" name="ApplicantIs" id="f-applicant-is_1" value="Executor" onclick="showMoreInfo(this);" />
                    Executor
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li id="f-container-applicant-moreinfo">
        <label for="f-applicant-moreinfo">More Info</label>
        <input type="text" name="ApplicantMoreInfo" id="f-applicant-moreinfo" />
    </li>




function showMoreInfo(x) {
    var bond = document.getElementById('f-applicant-bondamount');
    var y = bond.value;

    if (y > 100000 && x.value == "Administrator")  {
        document.getElementById('f-container-applicant-moreinfo').style.display = 'block';      
    }
    else if (y <= 100000 && x.value == "Administrator") {
        document.getElementById('f-container-applicant-moreinfo').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry. I wasn't very clear about what I'm trying. This code is part of a larger form... I want a section of form to appear if 2 prereq's are met: a radio selection with value 'x' and a text field with number greater than 'y'. If both are met, then more form will appear. It's all working except for the order in which the values are entered. If text comes first and then radio, it works fine. But if radio first and then text value, nothing happens unless radio button is clicked on again (and it isn't if text field `onblur`). Alone `onchange` works. But with `&& rad.value ==` it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Your code doesn't work because the `showMoreInfo(x)` function assumes that the x parameter will be a reference to one or the other of the radio buttons, but then your text input's onchange/onkeyup/whatever event is calling the same function and passing in a reference to itself - this is why it only works when you click the radio buttons. You could try something like the following instead, letting the function work out its own references to your HTML elements instead of passing them in:

```
function showMoreInfo() {
   var bond = document.getElementById('f-applicant-bondamount');
   var adminRadio = document.getElementById('f-applicant-is_0');
   // var theOtherRadioIfYouNeedIt = document.getElementById('f-applicant-is_1');

   var y = bond.value;

   if (y > 100000 && adminRadio.checked) {
      document.getElementById('f-container-applicant-moreinfo').style.display = 'block';
   }
   else if (y <= 100000 && adminRadio.checked) {
      document.getElementById('f-container-applicant-moreinfo').style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

My original point about keyboard events being inadequate still stands though.

My original answer:

As wombleton said, `onchange` only happens when focus leaves the field - which is why in your example clicking on the radio button makes the `onchange` happen. So as has been said already you can use `onkeyup` instead of `onchange`.

*But*, remember that there are several ways that the user can change the value in an input without using the keyboard (thus no `onkeyup`), e.g., drag-and-drop onto the input (drag out will change the focus, but if you're not using `onchange` any more...). Or right-click-context-menu-paste, cut or delete. Off-hand I'm not sure what the simplest way to cater for these is (I haven't needed to worry since I don't like having things on the page change as the user types within a field and I generally only need `onkeyup` to check specifically for the enter key), but there are onpaste and ondrop events you could look into.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely answer is that textfield's `onchange` [only fires when you blur from it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Events). Clicking anywhere except in the textfield should trigger the event.

You can use `onkeyup` instead.

Comment: `onchange` works fine on its own, so `onkeyup` isn't the solution. When I use either of these in conjunction with a radio value, the don't work. See my `function` above and new comment beneath to understand what I'm trying to do. At any rate, I will use `onkeyup` from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

onkeypress or onkeyup are the correct events to listen for changes to a text input field.  onkeypress fires when pressed or held, while onkeyup fires after a key has been released